# Create A See Through WPF Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

How can I make the `Expander` Control display top elements when it's collapsed?
I have a list-view wrapped within an `Expander` , and I want it to display the 5 first elements when it's collapsed.

Comment: You can update expander's header, when it is collapsed, to display top elements, but this won't be the same list view. Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: yes, how can i achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change header, using style trigger.
Something like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private const string sampleText =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget risus sit amet dolor malesuada scelerisque.";

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<string>(sampleText.Split());
        Header = "Items:";
        CollapsedHeader = $"Items: {string.Join(" ", Items.Take(5))}...";
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; }

    public string Header { get; }

    public string CollapsedHeader { get; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Expander>
        <Expander.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding CollapsedHeader}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Expander.Style>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </Expander>
</Window>
```

Result:

1) expanded:

[image]

2) collapsed:

[image]